# Configuring FileHelpers DateTimeConverter format at runtime

Tags: c#, csv, filehelpers

I have a need to import a CSV file, but need my users to be able to select the date format their CSV file is using for dates.

Currently, I have my date property declared as

```
    [FieldOrder(3)]
    [FieldConverter(ConverterKind.Date, "yyyyMMdd")]
    public DateTime contribution_date { get; set; }
```

However, my client might be uploading a file where the date format is out of their control, and might not be the existing format. This throws an exception when I try to parse the file.

Does anybody have a working example of how to change the DateTimeConverter's format (arg1) at runtime?

My mapped type is a domain object in our EF environment, so I'm hesitant to introduce the ClassBuilder (unless I can *start* a class builder with an existing class, which I'm not aware I can).

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the DelimitedClassBuilder to build a proxy class. I use this proxy class to map values from a .CSV file into .NET objects, then use reflection to retrieve the values from the object fields and map them onto my desired destination type.

It seems a little hacky to me, and I'm not 100% certain I'm using the tool as intended.

Can anyone confirm that reflection is the expected path for mapping values from these proxy objects?

Answer (score 0):

```
var converter = myEngine.Options.Fields[0].Converter;
var converterType = converter.GetType();
var FieldInfo = converterType.GetField("mFormat", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
FieldInfo.SetValue(converter, myDateFormatString);
```

That's how I did it, little bit hacky, but it worked!